How to get the directivity function of a planar 3D wave source? (Acoustics)
I am trying to model the directivity function of an electrostatic speaker. If I understand it right they propagate pressure evenly across their surface unlike traditional piston transducers:
https://youtu.be/KGhFYSk4zJI?si=_WlMiTt-R4cvTHwn&t=213 (skip to 3:33)
Circular piston speakers have a directivity function that uses a Bessel function:
https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/baffledpiston/baffledpiston.html
From what I understand, Bessel functions are mostly used to describe radiation from a circular source but since my electrostatic speaker is rectangular in shape (I might put a curve on it later like the one in the video (skip to 7:34)) and radiation is even across its surface, how would I derive a directivity function?
Or maybe someone else already has and if so can anyone please direct me to their paper?

Don’t get my word on that but I believe that the directivity pattern is going to be independent on the two axes. Now, on each axis you get a kind of “stacked” linear arrays of infinitesimal width. The directivity of each one of those is of the form $D \left( \phi \right) = \frac{\sin \left( \frac{\pi L}{\lambda} \cos \left( \phi \right) \right)}{\left( \frac{\pi L}{\lambda} \cos \left( \phi \right) \right)} = \textrm{sinc} \left( \frac{\pi L}{\lambda} \cos \left( \phi \right) \right)$. (cont.’)

(cont.’ed) Now, since directivity is independent on the two axes, for the “total” (3D) directivity you would get something like $D \left( \phi, \theta \right) = \textrm{sinc} \left( \frac{\pi L}{\lambda} \cos \left( \phi \right) \right) \textrm{sinc}( \left( \frac{\pi L}{\lambda} \cos \left( \theta \right) \right)$. Here $\phi$ is the azimuth angle in the range $\left[ 0, 2 \pi \right]$ and $\theta$ is the elevation angle in the range $\left[ 0, \pi \right]$.

Thank you! can you direct me to an article from where I can start learning how to do this? I want to learn the theory behind it

I would strongly suggest starting with the textbook “Optimum Array Processing - Part IV of Detection, Estimation and Modulation Theory” by Harry Van Trees. You can find all the basics in there about array processing. What you are looking for should be Chapter 4 in the textbook.

Thank you @ZaellixA

The book is a bit too pricey for me. I found this pdf tho from web.mit.edu that helped me bit to understand the function:
https://web.mit.edu/8.13/8.13c/references-fall/aip/aip-handbook-section3i.pdf
I'm going to leave it here if anyone is interested

Oh, damn… Apologies, I have institutional access to the book and completely missed the fact that not everyone is in the same situation. I’m really sorry for that and glad you found something that can help you. If anything else that is not behind a pay wall comes to mind I’ll throw it your way.

thank you @ZaellixA!
